# Why is a, b = 1 not allowed?

Tags: python, python-2.7, syntax

I was wondering about variables assignments and why is this allowed:

```
a = 1, 2

a = b = 1
```

but this is not allowed:

```
a, b = 1
```

What is the logic behind?
Thank you

Comment: What would the result be?

Comment: The `a, b = ` is valid in certain situations. eg `a, b = x` is fine if `x` is an iterable of length 2. In your version there's no clear thing that it could mean.

Comment: Because `a, b = 1` means something entirely different? That's universal across all programming languages, use different syntax to accomplish different things.

Comment: `a = 1, 2` Actually makes a tuple (1,2) with identifier "a",  `a ,b = 1` actually expects a iterable object on the right hand side define the values of a and b as 1st and 2nd element of an iterable object. This is quiet intuitive!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to assume you might be familiar with a language like C/C++, which is a statically-typed language. This means that the type of a variable must be declared when initialising a variable (eg you'd say `int a;`).

In C/C++, the syntax you are trying to do is valid syntax when doing `int a, b = 1;` (for example), because we're initialising two variables, a and b, to be integers, where the second one we're assigning a value 1.

However, Python is a dynamically typed language - the type of the variable does not need to be declared. Thus, when we do `a, b = 1`, we're actually using a feature Python has which is called "unpacking". Python is trying to *unpack* `1` to the variables `a` and `b` - but this is not possible since `1` is just a single piece of data - it's not a list or a tuple or whatever.

Because Python is dynamically typed, we can not just initiate a variable and not give it any value (like we do in C when we do `int a;`). When you do `a, b = 1`, it's trying to iterate through `1` and assign its contents to the variables `a` and `b`. Hence, the error `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`.

Comment: To me it looks more like *math* than C. In math, I'd say "a, b = 1" isn't unusual and means both a and b are 1. And Python is pretty mathy, for example also supporting "1 < x < 9" and meaning what a mathematician would mean with that, not what a C coder might mean with that.

Answer (score 2):

The left and right side are not symmetric. In

```
a = 1, 2
```

python does *packing* of the right-hand side arguments. The two comma-separated arguments create a  *tuple*, so this is equivalent to `a = (1, 2)`

With

```
a, b = 1
```

python tries to do *unpacking*. It assigns the first value of the right-hand expression to `a`, and then tries to assign the second value to `b`. Since there is no second value, this will fail. It will treat the value `1` as *iterable*, so will give `TypeError: int is not iterable`.

You should write something like `a, b = 1, 2`.

Comment: May as well include that you get a `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable` and that that error occurs as a consequence of python trying to unpack `1` and failing to do so.

Comment: I've upvoted both of the answers, as they both explain the observed behaviour well, albeit differently.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case python assumes a is a tuple of 1 and 2

```
>>> a = 1, 2
>>> a
(1, 2)
```

But `a, b = 1` you want to give values to a and b, so there must be two values for them, but you're only providing one i.e `1`. If you have a iterable of length of `2` then it would work.

```
>>> a, b = [6, 7]
>>> a
6
>>> b
7
```

Answer (score 0):

In python when you give two number/strings with , python interpreter thinks its a tuple

```
  a = 1, 2
```

in the above line you are creating tuple object called a

```
 a, b = 1
```

In the above line left hand side syntax is for a tuple , so right side it expects tuple value
so

```
a,b = 1,1
```

works